# Logical sequence of tasks in SSIS using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

[image]

I make a logical shema(look picture).
In every *Script task* I use **C#** code:

```
string curFile = @"D:\!_Package_Download\!_Download\file_name.xlsx";
File.Exists(curFile);
```

So few questions:

- why my first script task always work even when I delete file in the folder.

- and as result it is not working on failure?

Comment: What are you doing with the return value of `File.Exists`?

Comment: check if there is file in in the folder. I think if there is no file in the folder script will return FALSE and it will return TRUE if that file is there.

Comment: Can you post the code setting Dts.TaskResult  if any?

Comment: That is what `File.Exists` does, yes, but in your provided code sample you are not using the return value.

Comment: I guess I shoul add an "If..else" statement or "switch", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to control the failure/success of a script task based on your conditions you need to set it manually.

```
Dts.TaskResult = File.Exists(path)?(int)ScriptResults.Success:(int)ScriptResults.Failure;
```

Comment: This is works but on FAILURE next step(check stores) wont work.

Comment: You do need to do this separately in every script task.